# Is there a easy way to hide the flex preloader?

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

Is there a way to hide the preloader. One idea I have is to make a new one that is empty, but surely there must exist an easier way to do it.

It might sound like a dumb idea but in some situations it can be nice to just hide the preloader. Especially if it doesn't require a lot of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `usePreloader="false"` to your `mx:Application` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    usePreloader="false">
```